# Triggering an application on the arrival of a message(sms) in android phone

Tags: android

I want to trigger an application after the arrival of the sms. I using android based mobile phone. Can any body help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must create a listener for the event. [Here's](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/) a basic example on how to do it.